# Gulp Newbie: Files not compiling to dist folder

Tags: html, css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

This is my first time using Gulp, and I'm about to lose my mind. I thought I followed a walk-through very carefully, but it seems that none of my SASS files are compiling to the dist folder like I wanted. I am also getting an error in the browser that reads:

---

````
```
(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/normalize.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/dist/css/global_styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/dist/css/index.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/normalize.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/dist/css/global_styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/dist/css/index.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.```
````

---

My folder structure is as follows:

```
widgetsPage
  app
    js
      games.js
      in_the_works.js
      index.js
      mobile.js
      puzzle.js
      trivia.js
    scss
      games.scss
      global_styles.scss
      in_the_works.scss
      index.scss
      mobile.scss
      puzzle.scss
      trivia.scss
      weather.scss
    games.html
    in_the_works.html
    mobile.html
    normalize.css
    puzzle.html
    trivia.html
    weather.html
  dist
  Images
  node_modules
  gulpfile.js
  index.html
  package-lock.json
  package.json
```

---

And this is the gulpfile.js I used:

```
    var gulp = require("gulp"),
    sass = require("gulp-sass"),
    postcss = require("gulp-postcss"),
    autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer"),
    cssnano = require("cssnano"),
    sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps"),
    browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();

var paths = {
    styles: {
        // By using styles/**/*.sass we're telling gulp to check all folders for any sass file
        src: "app/scss/*.scss",
        // Compiled files will end up in whichever folder it's found in (partials are not compiled)
        dest: "../../dist/css"
    }

    // Easily add additional paths
    // ,html: {
    //  src: '...',
    //  dest: '...'
    // }
};

function style() {
    return gulp
        .src(paths.styles.src)
        // Initialize sourcemaps before compilation starts
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .on("error", sass.logError)
        // Use postcss with autoprefixer and compress the compiled file using cssnano
        .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer(), cssnano()]))
        // Now add/write the sourcemaps
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest))
        // Add browsersync stream pipe after compilation
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}




// A simple task to reload the page
function reload() {
    browserSync.reload();
}

// Add browsersync initialization at the start of the watch task
function watch() {
    browserSync.init({
        // You can tell browserSync to use this directory and serve it as a mini-server
        server: {
            // baseDir: "./src"
            proxy: "localhost"
        }
        // If you are already serving your website locally using something like apache
        // You can use the proxy setting to proxy that instead
        // proxy: "yourlocal.dev"
    });
    gulp.watch(paths.styles.src, style);
    // We should tell gulp which files to watch to trigger the reload
    // This can be html or whatever you're using to develop your website
    // Note -- you can obviously add the path to the Paths object
    //gulp.watch("src/*.html", reload);
    gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
}

// We don't have to expose the reload function
// It's currently only useful in other functions


// Don't forget to expose the task!
exports.watch = watch

// Expose the task by exporting it
// This allows you to run it from the commandline using
// $ gulp style
exports.style = style;

/*
 * Specify if tasks run in series or parallel using `gulp.series` and `gulp.parallel`
 */
var build = gulp.parallel(style, watch);

/*
 * You can still use `gulp.task` to expose tasks
 */
//gulp.task('build', build);

/*
 * Define default task that can be called by just running `gulp` from cli
 */
```

---

I'd appreciate any and all help, let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: What command are you using to run the build?

Comment: I'm using `gulp watch`

Comment: I would try `src: "./app/scss/*.scss",` in your `paths` object.  Note the leading `./`

Comment: And switch the MIME type from `text/html` to `text/css` in your css links in the html files.  Or just remove that altogether so it looks like this: `<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">` with your filename of course.

Comment: Add the leading `./` in my comment above because it should be relative to your gulpfile.js position.  `"app/scss/*.scss"` looks like it is in a folder named `app` located under where gulpfile.js is - which it is not in your case.

Comment: @Mark Ok, I changed the `paths` object. I also removed the `type` attribute from the links, but nothing has changed. I still have the same errors in the console.

Comment: Maybe a caching issue?  Kill the cache in your browser, try again.

Comment: `(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/normalize.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/dist/css/global_styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/dist/css/index.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

Comment: @Mark Sorry about the messy text but I got those errors after clearing the cache

Comment: There was also this one: `GET http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203817/discussion-between-enzie-riddle-and-mark).